# Unable to set DesiredCapabilities for HtmlUnitDriver - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am using this code to set Capabilities for my HtmlUnitDriver:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);  
String browsername = getBrowser();
Platform platform = getPlatform();
System.out.println(browsername + " , " + platform.name());
caps.setBrowserName(browsername);
caps.setPlatform(platform); 

HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(caps); 
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 

Capabilities caps2 = driver.getCapabilities();
System.out.println(caps2.getBrowserName() + " , " + caps2.getPlatform());
```

But I get this output:

```
opera , XP
htmlunit , WIN8_1
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.htmlUnit();
capabilities.setBrowserName(<browser_name>);
capabilities.setPlatform(<platform>);
capabilities.setVersion(<version>);
driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(capabilities);
```

Hope it would work.

Comment: Hey, I have tried all possible DesiredCapabilities.(module) and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I managed to overcome this problem with this code:

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(new BrowserVersion(
            "Firefox", "5.0 (Windows)", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0", 66));
```

Comment: Yes, there are always some more time to revert things. Or gets things worse.